# Android Studio Preview not able to render constraintLayout Barrier item

Tags: kotlin, android-constraintlayout

(on Android Studio version 3.5.3)
The barrier works fine at run time, but AS preview is not able to find it/render it

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1, view2"
        />
```

result:

[image]

barrier shows up as a gray box as if preview doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using older `dependency`, then please use one of them:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4' // For MotionLayout
```